# How can I unbless an object in Perl?

Tags: perl, oop

From [perldoc -f bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html):

> `bless REF,CLASSNAME`
>
> This function tells the thingy referenced by `REF` that it is now
>           an object in the `CLASSNAME` package.

Is there any way of obtaining an unblessed structure without unnecessary copying?

Comment: See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=183348

Comment: @Ether: For example, Template::Toolkit. The dot operator `'.'` is used to access into lists and hashes or to call object methods. TT always tries an object method first.

Comment: FWIW I have need of `unbless` because `YAML::Any::Dump()` will retain an object's blessed nature, I don't want to store that, but sometimes the data hashes I'm dumping are blessed. Also `Moose->new` is very picky and won't take a blessed hashref for an argument.

Comment: Yep, dumping objects is often the reason.   The "why would you need this" comment is often spouted by an ideologue‎.   It's simultaneously unhelpful, condescending and indicative of ignorance.

Comment: Well, the "why would you need this" is often trying to get at the real problem because people ask about a solution they think they need instead of a cause (the [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)). In this case, the original post had no motivation for the suggested solution.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Data::Structure::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Structure::Util)

> `unbless($ref)`
>
> Remove the blessing from any objects found within the passed data structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Scalar::Util qw( refaddr );
use Data::Structure::Util qw( unbless );

my $x = bless { a => 1, b => 2 } => 'My';

printf "%s : %s\n", ref $x, refaddr $x;

unbless $x;

printf "%s : %s\n", ref $x, refaddr $x;
```

Output:

```
My : 237356
HASH : 237356
```

Comment: This solution should make notice on the fact that ALL values in a data structure that happen to be blessed, will be unblessed too, not just the original data structure object.

Comment: I'm surprised that it cannot be done with Perl core functions; specifically why `bless $x, ''`  (or `bless $x, undef`) won't do (it blesses to `main` for some reasons), and if you try `bless $x, 'HASH'`, you will get a `HASH=HASH(0x259c128)`.

Answer (score 34):

[Data::Structure::Util](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Data::Structure::Util) has an `unbless` function that will do it for you. As Erik points out, [JSON::XS](http://www.metacpan.org/module/JSON::XS) won't normally accept blessed references (although I wish it would just ignore that and deal with the data structure). There's no way around it in this case.

But consider why do you think you need to unbless it. Are you doing this for one of your own classes or a different class? This sounds suspiciously like The Wrong Thing To Do. There might be a better way.

You have the same problem as breaking encapsulation because you have to assume that you know what the internal structure of the reference is. If you are going to do that, you can just ignore the object-oriented stuff and access the structure directly.

If you are going to do this for your own class, consider providing a method to return a data structure (which doesn't have to be the original structure) instead of changing the object.

You mention in a follow-up comment that you might be doing this to get around some Template Toolkit behavior. I had this situation in two ways depending on the situation:

- Only pass the data you need to the template instead of the whole object.
- Add methods to the object to get the data you want in the template.

Perl is DWIM, but TT is even DWIMmier, which is unfortunate sometimes.

---

Here's a quick hack where I define a `TO_JSON` in `UNIVERSAL` so it applies to all objects. It makes a deep copy, unblesses it, and returns the data structure.

```
#!perl
use v5.10;

sub UNIVERSAL::TO_JSON {
    my( $self ) = shift;

    use Storable qw(dclone);
    use Data::Structure::Util qw(unbless);

    my $clone = unbless( dclone( $self ) );

    $clone;
    }

my $data = bless {
    foo => bless( [], 'Local::Array' ),
    quack => bless( {
        map { $_ => bless [$_, $_**2], 'Local::Array' } 
            grep { is_prime } 1 .. 10
        }, 'Local::Hash' ),
    }, 'Local::Hash';

use JSON::XS;
my $jsonner = JSON::XS->new->pretty->convert_blessed(1);
say $jsonner->encode( $data );
```

Comment: unbless is often helpful, like when you're debugging an internal state and want to dump a blessed object in a tight loop...with json::xs because Dumper is 100 times slower, and json::xs won't dump a blessed object.... even if it's just a hashref.

Comment: Indeed, JSON::XS is the one place I haven't been able to do it any other way. Thanks, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 30):

If you know what your object is backed by, you could do this without using packages.

Hash

```
$obj = bless {}, 'Obj';
print ref $obj, "\n";
$obj = { %$obj };
print ref $obj, "\n";
```

Array

```
$obj = bless [], 'Obj';
print ref $obj , "\n";
$obj = [ @$obj ];
print ref $obj, "\n";
```

Scalar

```
$obj = bless \$a, "Obj";
print ref $obj, "\n";
$obj = \${ $$obj };
print ref $obj, "\n";
```

Comment: +1 because this exactly solved my problem, namely I just wanted to "temporarily" access the underlying data structure of the object (a Hash) to easily Dump it with YAML::Tiny.

Comment: This only works if only the top level is blessed. Hash values or array elements may themselves be blessed references.

Comment: Considering that (at least) 99% of all blessed objects are either `HASH`, `ARRAY`, or `SCALAR` one could even code it (`$obj = { %$obj } if ref $obj eq 'HASH'; # etc.`. Also it may be worth so point out that it  does not unbless the object, but creates an unblessed copy of the object.

Answer (score 12):

<s>[Acme::Curse](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme::Curse)</s> :)

**Update:** Thank you, Ivan! I mixed up modules. Actually I wanted to give a link to  [Acme::Damn](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme::Damn) :))

**P. S.** See also [Acme::Sneeze](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Acme::Sneeze) :)

**P. P. S.** It has no real use, that's why it's `Acme::`. See brian's post.

Comment: But this module creates copy of the object.

Comment: Attributed to Mike Andrews in alt.sysadmin.recovery: "Perl already has _bless_, and we know what it does, right?  Perl should also have _smite_, and we know what it should do, too.  If more languages had _smite_ implemented, the remaining programmers would be better than the current average."